# An alternative to Enterprise Architect for Database Engineering and documentation

Tags: rest, database-design, architecture, documentation, development-process

Good morning/afternoon/evening everyone :)

Currently, I am trying to identify applications that will allow me to store the database model and generate nice documentation along with business logic chapters.
So far best choose is Enterprise Architect that is storing DB model in its own repository, that will allow me to design DB model change and compare it with dev model later, furthermore, it can generate nice business/technical documentation out of the model in the repository.

For years I have been using RedGate SQL Doc which is perfect for technical documents, but I have to inject some business logic stuff like diagrams of relations and a short description.

First thought: keep the logic part in different word and just combine them later with SQLDoc and just keep two models in branches: Dev, Design to compare them later with VS. Would work.

Second thought: let's use dedicated software for this, found EA that works like a charm but there is always BUT. One of my DB has more than 10k artifacts (tables/fn/sp/) and basically, EA stops working...

So I am looking for alternative ways, I belive this is best place to do it :)

Comment: I'm not sure that EA is the best choice. I used PowerDesigner for many years and find it more adapted to database modeling. Reverse engineering of 10K artifacts is long but achieves the end. A free Oracle Database Designer may be useful, too. However, you still need to write 10K notes to generate a business logic chapters.